# Unable to validate json_decode associative array elements

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I want to do form validation in php and send any errors to the ajax call.
I posted the form inputs as an array with named indexes from the ajax call to php controller. There I decoded it using json_decode(). Now I want to access each of those elements and do validations for them.

**JS:**

```
function init_order()
{
    var noOfSims = $('#a_noofsims').val();
    var network = $('#a_network').val();
    var plan = $('#plan').val();
    var o_data={};
    o_data["a_noOfSims"]=noOfSims;
    o_data["a_network"]=network;
    o_data["plan"]=plan;
    js_data=JSON.stringify(o_data);
    $.ajax({
        url:"<?php echo site_url('sim_orders_ajax/add')?>/",
        type:"POST",
        dataType:"JSON",
        data:{order_data:js_data},
        success:function(data)
        {
            alert(data.status);
        },
        error:function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            alert("Error in adding order");
        }
    });
```

**PHP:**

```
public function add()
{
    $order_data=$_POST['order_data'];
    $j_data=json_decode($order_data, true);
    $noOfSims = $j_data["a_noOfSims"];
    $network = $j_data["a_network"];
    $plan = $j_data["plan"];

    if($noOfSims=='')
      $data="Error";
    else
      $data="No Error"

    echo json_encode(array("status" => $data));
}
```

On submitting the form, it goes to ajax error function. If I remove the validation code snippet, it goes to success function. I'm unable to do anything with the elements from the json_decode associative array. I don't understand what the problem is.

**EDIT**

Hi, I'm so sorry. As mentioned in the comments, it was the typo that was causing g the problem. Thanks for the help!

Comment: `if($noOFims=='')` where you have mention this `$noOFims` variable ?

Comment: typo ... `$noOFims != $noOfSims`

Comment: Try echo '$j_data', to see what actually returns from json_decode()

Comment: Its seems your logic is wrong ...because it will go in error function only if there is any exception in your server side code...but in this case you are simply returning an object from server

Comment: I don't see any proof in your question about the validity of the JSON you're sending. Care to show some actual JSON so we can see what your code is sending and accepting? (also on a security note, NEVER EVER trust user input. You have zero guarantee that the JSON your php gets sent is safe - validate everything)

Answer (score 1):

There is no real reason to need to send  the data object as json. You could just send your `o_data` object and jQuery will form encode it for you:

```
function init_order() {

  var o_data = {
    a_noOfSims: $('#a_noofsims').val(),
    a_network: $('#a_network').val(),
    plan: $('#plan').val()
  };

  $.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo site_url('sim_orders_ajax/add')?>/",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "JSON",
    data: o_data,
    success: .....
  });
 }
```

PHP

```
$noOfSims = $_POST["a_noOfSims"];
$network = $_POST["a_network"];
$plan = $_POST["plan"];

$data = empty($noOfSims) ? "Error" : "No Error";
echo json_encode(array("status" => $data));
```